I upgraded React Native from 0.72.3 to 0.74.3 and I keep getting these 4 errors once the Android application is built. Any clues?
The React Native Android application builds successfully but I keep seeing these 4 errors in the Metro terminal:
 ERROR  Error: [Reanimated] Native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized.
See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#native-part-of-reanimated-doesnt-seem-to-be-initialized for more details., js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "AbleTo" with {"rootTag":11}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "AbleTo" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in LogBox(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in LogBox(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

I don't understand why Reanimated is not initialized as I've gone through the setup and have covered all the steps. It was working just fine before the upgrade. I also can't quite understand what the other 3 errors are even referring to. Anyone got any tips?
